# Spring Boot Kafka Connection Issue with Docker on WSL2: Broker may not be available (Node -1 Error)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka, wsl-2

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application and using Docker on WSL2 to run a Kafka broker. However, I've run into an issue when my Spring Boot application attempts to connect to the Kafka broker. The error message I'm encountering is as follows:

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id2-2, groupId=group_id2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

To provide a bit more context, my Spring Boot application is running on my Windows machine, while the Kafka broker is hosted within a Docker container on WSL2, where I'm managing my Docker setup through Portainer.

I've configured the Docker Compose file with specific settings, and I've ensured that the necessary ports are exposed:

```
version: '3'

services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9094:9094'
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9094,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://172.23.0.1:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
```

I've also setup the configuration in my Spring Boot application which is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

So I attempted to test the connectivity using the the 'telnet' command, and it was successful, confirming that there's connectivity between the two environments, but I don't know what is causing the issue.

I've tried setting up the IP address of the hypervisor directly instead of using 'localhost' but unfortunately, I'm still encountering the same issue.

Comment: Remove network_mode: host since that doesn't work as you want in WSL2, and don't use  IP addresses as advertised listener. Telnet doesn't test _advertised listeners_ are correct, only that the port is open